# How do I create a responsive glow coming from the upper right corner?

Tags: css, position, css-position, glow

I'm  trying to make a glow coming from the upper right corner in css, something similar to this:
[image]

I tried making a div with filter:blur() and positioning it with absolute, but that causes problems with my viewport since this has to be responsive aswell.

Does anyone know how to make this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by a "*responsive glow*," what is it "responsive" to? You say you've tried to do this with `filter: blur()`, but you don't show how. Without sharing your code, and your attempts, we can't help you except by making guesses (which isn't something we tend to do) and getting incredibly lucky.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use filter:blur but simply add the following:

```
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

If you want it to be responsive size wise also add this:

```
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
```

Comment: Already did this, but because my spread is so big I have to go outside of my viewport

Comment: then make top & right minus or change height & width